# SOLVED - Makefile: Multiple Definition of Function (Actually a C++ lesson)

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, g++

I'm trying to write more sophisticated makefiles, but my explorations have gotten me into a multiple definition issue.

The program is meant to brute-force a marble maze, so I have a class for the game board declared in `marbleBoard.h`, with its implementation written in `marbleBoard.cpp`. The `.cpp` file `#includes` the `.h` file. The main program is written in `marble.cpp`. The Variables `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, and `WEST` refer to bit masks that symbolize walls, and are defined in `marbleBoard.h` outside of the class.

I based my makefile on MrBook's tutorial [Makefiles](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/).

Here is the Makefile code:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMPILER=g++

CFLAGS=-c -g -std=c++14

all: marble

marble: marble.o marbleBoard.o
    $(COMPILER) marble.o marbleBoard.o -o marble

marble.o: marble.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) marble.cpp

marbleBoard.o: marbleBoard.cpp marbleBoard.h
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) marbleBoard.cpp marbleBoard.h

clean:
    rm *o marble
```

This is the output I recieve:

```
[uthranuil@Palantir marble]$ make
g++ -c -g -std=c++14 marbleBoard.cpp marbleBoard.h
g++ marble.o marbleBoard.o -o marble
marbleBoard.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `NORTH'
marble.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
marbleBoard.o: In function `marbleBoard::marbleBoard()':
/home/uthranuil/csci242/marble/marbleBoard.cpp:6: multiple definition of `EAST'
marble.o:(.data+0x1): first defined here
marbleBoard.o: In function `marbleBoard::marbleBoard()':
/home/uthranuil/csci242/marble/marbleBoard.cpp:6: multiple definition of `SOUTH'
marble.o:(.data+0x2): first defined here
marbleBoard.o: In function `marbleBoard::marbleBoard()':
/home/uthranuil/csci242/marble/marbleBoard.cpp:6: multiple definition of `WEST'
marble.o:(.data+0x3): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:10: marble] Error 1
```

I have spent a lot of time looking for answers and trying different solutions. Here is a list of Q/As I have read:
[Function multiple definition linker error building on GCC - Makefile issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940191/function-multiple-definition-linker-error-building-on-gcc-makefile-issue)
[Makefile: multiple definition and undefined reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085490/makefile-multiple-definition-and-undefined-reference-error?s=1%7C3.3091)
[Makefile: multiple definition of **TMC_END**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608723/makefile-multiple-definition-of-tmc-end?s=2%7C3.1407)
[Error in makefile: multiple definition of _start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237490/error-in-makefile-multiple-definition-of-start?s=3%7C2.6526)
[multiple definition errors when using makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717841/multiple-definition-errors-when-using-makefile?s=4%7C2.3881)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Not a makefile problem. Variable declarations in include files, variable definitions in .cpp files (unless they are const or maybe static).

Comment: Thank you very much! Defining the compass directions as static variables solved it.

Comment: I qualified static with "maybe" as it is normally NOT a good solution. I can't think of a case that I would actually recommend that. In most cases it will likely cause other problems. Unless you are dealing with true constants, you should almost always go with a declaration (extern) in the header file with a definition in one .cpp. That is, if you really, truly need a global variable,

Comment: And if you are using true constants, then do use const.

Comment: Okay, I took your advice, and moved the definition into the .cpp file. It actually works better. Thank you very much @AviBerger.

Comment: As of C++17, use `inline` on your constants to allow defining them in the header and avoid certain subtle traps if you take references to them (*e.g.*, by calling `std::min` on one).